# Generic Constructor Issues in Stack Array Implementation?

Tags: java, generics, constructor, stack

I'm working on a generic stack implementation in Java and have run into a few issues with the constructor. The class Stack226Array implements Stack226, which was given to us. So, I have my constructor declared as follows:

```
public void Stack226Array(int initialCapacity) {
    this.stack = (T[]) new Object[initialCapacity];
    this.top = 0;
}
```

and am calling it like this:

```
Stack226<Integer> intStack = new Stack226Array<>(10);
```

which returns the error:

```
 constructor Stack226Array in class Stack226Array<T> cannot be applied to given types;
Stack226<Integer> intStack = Stack226Array<Integer>(10);
required: no arguments
found: int
```

possibly related issue, but when I try to have a default constructor declared as:

```
public void Stack226Array() {
    this(100);
}
```

it returns an error that a call to this must be first statement in the constructor. Much thanks to anyone who can help! Let me know if you need more code snippets.

Comment: Your default constructor has return type void. No return type for constructors! And your previous code has syntax errors, you should post correct code for people to help. Please correct the 1st line (this.stack...) Because that seems to be important

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem for both your constructors is that you have put a return type of void. You cannot have a return type on constructors. That is why the constructor is not found and compiler thinks there is only a default constructor.